# How to make parenthesis matching work in XEmacs?

Tags: match, xemacs, parentheses

I tried using all options in the menu setting Options|Display|Paren Highlighting, but nothing works - no parenthesis match is performed. I also tried setting explicitly `(paren-mode 'blink-paren t)` in my init file, but that did not help either. Any ideas what may be happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had paren mode working long enough in my XEmacs that I forget what exactly I did to turn it on, but I did dig these things out which might help.

From my .xemacs/init.el:

```
(require 'paren)
```

From my .xemacs/custom.el as part of custom-set-variables:

```
'(paren-mode (quote sexp) nil (paren))
'(show-paren-mode t)
```

-John